# ERROR: AddressSanitizer: heap-buffer-overflow on address

Tags: vector, while-loop, c++17

The problem is for Leet Code Intersection of Two Arrays. when I run code, it gave me no error and was working just fine giving the correct output. But when I try to submit, it gave me some weird error. I don't have any idea where and what the issue is.

This is my solution:

[image: my solution]
[image: run code output]

and this is the error I am getting in Leet Code on submitting:

```
[![runtime error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vaug.jpg)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vaug.jpg)
```

Comment: On the last iteration of the loop, when `i == n-1`, you are doing `i++; a=arr1[i];`, accessing an index out of bounds. Whereupon your program exhibits undefined behavior.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text. For more information, please see the Meta FAQ entry [Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors/285557#285557)